# Tab Completion in VS Code Terminal doesn't complete the highlighted command

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, terminal, tab-completion

When I start typing a command into the integrated `pwsh` terminal prompt in Visual Studio Code, auto-complete suggests some ideas.

**Example**:

- I type `.` and the terminal suggests `.\.venv\Scripts\activate`:
- [image]

But when I hit `TAB` which is my intuition to accept the suggestion, nothing happens.

How do I get the `TAB` key to **accept the suggested command**?

Comment: with the Right Arrow ;)

Comment: Sends @SantiagoSquarzon a heart emoji! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is detailed in the [**Using predictors in PSReadLine**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/shell/using-predictors?view=powershell-7.3#changing-keybindings) documentation:

> - `AcceptSuggestion` is built within `ForwardChar`, which is bound to <kbd>RightArrow</kbd> by default